# Banner 100% width extends to window size, but not document size

Tags: html, css

We have a iamge banner on our web page that is a gradient that is repeated on the x-axis. The problem is, if our content on our web page (which is dynamically created based on data in our database) spans a width greater than the window width, then our banner no longer spans the entire width of the document when scrolled. Anyone know how to fix this?

A simple example is posted below. The blue is our "banner" the "red" is our content.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        *{
            padding:0;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        #header{
            height:80px;
            background-color:blue;
            width:100%;
        }

        #content{
            width:1500px;
            background-color:red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"><h1>TEST</h1></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the header inside the content div. Like this:

```
...
</head>

<div id="content">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>

</html>
```

Even better, add a wrapper:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        *{
            padding:0;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width:1500px;    
        }

        #header{
            height:80px;
            background-color:blue;
            width:100%;
        }

        #content{
            width:100%;
            background-color:red;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"><h1>TEST</h1></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a min-width on your `#header` that equals the `#content` width would do it:

```
#header{
    height:80px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 1500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put a

```
<div id="wrapper"> header & content </div>
```

around everything... make wrapper `position:relative`, so 100% header is the width of the wrapper, which will be whatever content is.